Why is $T_{max}< \infty$ a consequence of $E(u_0) < 0$?
I have a question regarding the maximal existance time of the following PDE:
Lets consider the PDE:
\begin{matrix}
 u_t - \Delta u & = & \lambda u + |u|^{p-1}u  & \ x \in \Omega, t > 0 \newline
 u & = & 0 & \ x \in \partial \Omega, t > 0 \newline
 u(x,0) & = & u_{0}(x) & \ x \in \Omega 
 \end{matrix}
with $p > 1, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $u_o \in L^{\infty} \cap H^1_0(\Omega)$ and assume that $\Omega$ is bounded. If now $E(u_0) < 0$ then it follows that $T_{max}(u_0) < \infty$.
My question is, why is that?
I know that by defining a help function $\psi(t) := \Vert u(t) \Vert_2^2$, multiplying the PDE with this $\psi(t)$ and doing some rearranging, I can get the inequality
\begin{matrix}
    \frac{1}{2}\psi'(t) \geq -2E(u_0) + C\psi(t)^{(p+1)/2}
\end{matrix}
with $C = C(p,\Omega) > 0$ being some constant and $E(u(\cdot))$ being the Energy functional
\begin{matrix}
E(u) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{\Omega} (|\nabla u|^2 - \lambda u^2) \mathrm{d}x - \frac{1}{p+1}\int_{\Omega} |u|^{p+1} \mathrm{d}x
\end{matrix}
Since we assumed $E(u_0) < 0$ we get
\begin{matrix}
\psi'(t) \geq  C_1\psi(t)^{(p+1)/2}
\end{matrix}
Now from this apperently one can obtain that $T_{max}(u_0) < \infty$
My idea was to do something like this:
\begin{matrix}
\frac{\psi(t) - \psi(0)}{t} \to \psi'(0) \qquad \text{ as } t \to 0
\end{matrix}
and then using our inequality to get the Term $t$ which we then let approach $T_{max}$:
\begin{matrix}
\psi(t) - \psi(0) \geq C_1\psi(0)^{\frac{p+1}{2}}t \qquad (1)
\end{matrix}
I found in an old research paper that apparently I am supposed to land at
\begin{matrix}
\psi(t)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \geq \left[ \psi(0)^{-\frac{p-1}{2}}-\frac{p-1}{2} 2ct \right]^{-1} \qquad (2)
\end{matrix}
This would make sence since from here if we rearrange for $t$ we can get an upper bound for $T_{max}$:
\begin{matrix}
T_{max} \leq \frac{1}{C(p-1)}\psi(0)^{-\frac{p-1}{2}} < \infty
\end{matrix}
I just can't see how I get from (1) to (2) or if this is even the right approach. I would really appreciate some help.
Best Regards George

We know that the solution $y(t)$ to the ODE $y' = C_1 y^{(p+1)/2}$ with initial data $\psi(0)>0$ blows up in finite time, since $p>1$. Since $\psi$ satisfies the same initial value problem with $\geq$ replacing $=$, we believe it should grow even faster than $y(t)$ and also blow up.
To make this rigorous, let $q=(p+1)/2$, and divide $\psi' \geq C_1 \psi^q$ by $\psi^q$ to write
$$
\frac d {dt} \left(\frac 1 {1-q}\frac 1 {\psi^{q-1}}\right) \geq C_1,
$$
or, after integrating from $0$ to $t$,
$$
\frac 1 {1-q}\left(\frac 1 {\psi^{q-1}(t)} - \frac 1 {\psi^{q-1}(0)}\right) \geq C_1 t.
$$
Rearranging this, one gets
$$
\psi(t)^{q-1} \geq \frac 1 {\psi(0)^{1-q} -C_1(q-1) t},
$$
which is your formula (2) up to renaming constants and translating from $q$ back to $p$.
